# python numpy swap tuples with and without list index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, object

So there is a difference between these two lines underscored below. And I guess that the lower one is just renaming the portion where the top one actually switches the numpy arrays. Where can I look this up? What is the proper way to switch such objects?

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros([2,5,5])
x[1] = 0


x[0], x[1] = x[[1]], x[[0]]
#vs
x[0], x[1] = x[1], x[0]
#=========================
```

Comment: `x[[0,1]] = x[[1,0]],` is better. Or even `x=x[::-1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is more evident if you use different values:

```
x = np.arange(50).reshape((2,5,5))
```

it gives:

```
[[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
  [ 5  6  7  8  9]
  [10 11 12 13 14]
  [15 16 17 18 19]
  [20 21 22 23 24]]

 [[25 26 27 28 29]
  [30 31 32 33 34]
  [35 36 37 38 39]
  [40 41 42 43 44]
  [45 46 47 48 49]]]
```

Now let's look both ways:

After `x[0], x[1] = x[[1]], x[[0]]`, all is fine, we get:

```
array([[[25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        [35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
        [40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
        [45, 46, 47, 48, 49]],

       [[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]])
```

But after `x[0], x[1] = x[1], x[0]`, we get:

```
array([[[25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        [35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
        [40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
        [45, 46, 47, 48, 49]],

       [[25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        [35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
        [40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
        [45, 46, 47, 48, 49]]])
```

The fact is that numpy is not Python! In first method, we take copies of the subarrays and then assign them back into x, so everything is fine. In second method, the exchange is done at the C level so `x[0]` receives values from `x[1]` and then `x[1]` receives back... its own original values!

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but what is the difference between x[0] and x[[0]]. The former is just a different pointer to the same, so is the latter then an actual copy? Would it be more appropriate to write 
x[0],x[1] = np.copy(x[1]), np.copy(x[0])?
 Because this syntax looks a bit odd x[0], x[1] = x[[1]], x[[0]].

Comment: @Sadikov: It looks odd, but it is commonly used in Python or Pandas. It means to use an iterable of rows (or columns) identifiers to build a subset of the original object. And when it comes to copy vs. view, it is often hard to guess.

Comment: `numpy` is python, but not python lists.

Comment: @hpaulj: what I mean is that numpy comes with its own conventions which are not the common Python ones: you cannot simply swap ndarray elements, the result of a comparisons of arrays is an array and not a boolean, etc. All that does make sense in numpy context but is misleading for Python programmers when they learn numpy.